# correct use of "The" in example sentences

Tags: articles

I don't know English grammar, somehow I normally just "sense it". However, the following sentence have me beat:

> Amplitude of component P97, elicited by stimulus onset, did not depend on time.

Should there be a "The" before amplitude or not? Both seems fine for me.

Comment: I think the sentence reads better with a definite article added. But I'm not so sure I'd argue that the article _must_ be present.

Comment: +1 @J.R. In technical writing (as this seems to be) (the) articles are often elided, and phrases "condensed" as in _elicited by stimulus onset_ for _elicited by the onset of a stimulus._ This could even be called a component of technical style, I think, although to me it is easier to read in its expanded form.

Comment: @PED - That's an excellent example of why an O.P. should [tell us where they found their quote](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be technical style writing. in these texts, the writers usually try and condense their writing to take up less space. if you were looking for **Queens english grammar**, then the correct answer would be to add the definite article. however this depends on the context of the component being described.

Comment: -1 for using nonstandard capitalization